# Performance: FillBehavior.Stop vs FillBehavior.HoldEnd

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, animation

I have a WPF program that has quite a lot of animations. I've become concerned recently that the animations become sluggish after a while.

Would it make a difference to the performance if with every animation I used `FillBehavior.Stop` and then set the value manually in the `Completed` event rather than using `FillBehavior.HoldEnd`

Comment: Have you just tried it? Most of the time, only *you* can truly answer a performance question.

Comment: I'm actually trying it as we speak but it will take a long time and I was basically wondering if anyone knew weather or not I was wasting my time

Comment: @BradleyDotNET well,only you (him)), or a good profiler ...

Comment: Would it make a difference?  Probably.  Will it make a *perceivable* difference or actually solve your problem?  Only one way to find out :).  As a matter of style (driven mostly by OCD) I avoid `HoldEnd` whenever possible.  I dislike the idea of leaving animations attached simply to maintain the end value.  My reasoning is mostly philosophical; I have never measured the real-world impact.

Comment: And usually you could just set the final property value right after starting the animation and thus avoid attaching a Completed handler.